Most efficient way of defining the following sets for every step $n$
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, how do we compute sets $A_n$ and $B_n$ below:

Let $A_1=[0,2/3)$. Let $B_1=(2/3,1]$.
If $A_n$ is a union of intervals, then for each interval cut out the
middle $1/2^{n+1}$ of the interval and send it to $B_n$. Similarly,
for each interval in $B_n$ cut out the middle $1/(2^n)$ and send it to
$A_n$. Each set less what’s cut out plus what was transferred
determines $A_{n+1}$,$B_{n+1}$ .

(Edit 2: Note I define $A_n$ and $B_n$ as half-open intervals since I want to partition the reals into sets $A$ and $B$ that are dense (with positive  measure) in every sub-interval of $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$. For more info see this and this post. Thus, it wouldn't be mathematically appropriate if we have that all intervals in $A_n$ and $B_n$ are closed.)

Here is my attempt. We start with:
(Edit 1: Below, I made changes to the code.)
Clear["Global`*"]
A[1] = 0 <= x < 2/3 (*A1=[0,2/3)*)
B[1] = 2/3 <= x < 1 (*B1=[2/3,1)*)

Taking the upper and lower bound of intervals $A_1$ and $B_1$
a[1, 1] = A[1][[1]] (*Lowerbound of A1*)
a[1, 2] = A[1][[5]] (*Upperbound of A1*)
b[1, 1] = B[1][[1]] (*Lowerbound of B1*)
b[1, 2] = B[1][[5]] (*Upperbound of B1*)

Defining $A_2$ and $B_2$
(Edit 3: I made $1/2^{2+1}$ and $1/2^{2}$, $1/2^{1+1}$ and $1/2^{1}$. I apologize for my stupidity.)
A[2] = Reduce[a[1, 1] <= x <= (a[1, 1] + a[1, 2])/2 - 1/2 (1/2^(1 + 1)) (a[1, 2] - a[1, 1]) || 
       (a[1, 1] + a[1, 2])/2 + 1/2 (1/2^(1 + 1)) (a[1, 2] - a[1, 1]) <= x < a[1, 2] || 
       (b[1, 1] + b[1, 2])/2 - 1/2 (1/2^(1)) (b[1, 2] - b[1, 1]) <= x < (b[1, 1] + b[1, 2])/2+
       1/2 (1/2^(1)) (b[1, 2] - b[1, 1]), {x}] (*A2*)

B[2] = Reduce[b[1, 1] <= x <= (b[1, 1] + b[1, 2])/2 - 1/2 (1/2^(1)) (b[1, 2] - b[1, 1]) || 
       (b[1, 1] + b[1, 2])/2 + 1/2 (1/2^(1)) (b[1, 2] - b[1, 1]) <= x < b[1, 2] ||
       (a[1, 1] + a[1, 2])/2 - 1/2 (1/2^(1 + 1)) (a[1, 2] - a[1, 1]) <= x < (a[1, 1] + a[1, 2])/2 + 
     1/2 (1/2^(1 + 1)) (a[1, 2] - a[1, 1]), {x}] (*B2*)

Repeating the same process for the each of the $3$ intervals of $A_2$, each of the $9$ intervals of $A_3$, and each of the $3^{n-1}$ intervals of $A_n$.
a[x_, 1, i_] := A[x][[3^(i - 1)]][[1]] 
(*If i is a number in [1,3^(x-1)], then a[x,1,i] is the Lowerbound of the 3^(i-1)th interval of A_n*)
a[x_, 2, i_] := A[x][[3^(i - 1)]][[5]] 
(*If i is a number in [1,3^(x-1)], then a[x,1,i] is the Upperbound of the 3^(i-1)th interval of A_n*)
b[x_, 1, i_] := B[x][[3^(i - 1)]][[1]] 
(*If i is a number in [1,3^(x-1)], then b[x,1,i] is the Lowerbound of the 3^(i-1)th interval of B_n*)
b[x_, 2, i_] := B[x][[3^(i - 1)]][[5]] 
(*If i is a number in [1,3^(x-1)], then b[x,1,i] is the Upperbound of the 3^(i-1)th interval of B_n*)

A[s_, i_] := Reduce[a[s, 1, i] <= x <= (a[s, 1, i] + a[s, 2, i])/2 - 1/2 (1/2^(s)) 
             (a[s, 2, i] - a[s, 1, i]) || (a[s, 1, i] + a[s, 2, i])/2 + 1/2 (1/2^(s)) 
             (a[s, 2, i] - a[s, 1, i]) <=x < a[s, 2, i] || (b[s, 1, i] + b[s, 2, i])/2 - 
             1/2 (1/2^(s-1)) (b[s, 2, i] - b[s, 1, i]) <= x < (b[s, 1, i] + b[s, 2, i])/2 
             + 1/2 (1/2^(s-1)) (b[s, 2, i] - b[s, 1, i]), {x}] 
(*Changes the 3^(i-1)th interval of A_n using the description in above the attempt.*)

 B[s_, i_] := Reduce[b[s, 1, i] <= x <= (b[s, 1, i] + b[s, 2, i])/2 - 1/2 (1/2^(s-1)) 
              (b[s, 2, i] - b[s, 1, i]) || (b[s, 1, i] + b[s, 2, i])/2 + 1/2 (1/2^(s-1)) 
              (b[s, 2, i] - b[s, 1, i]) <= x <b[s, 2, i] || (a[s, 1, i] + a[s, 2, i])/2 - 
              1/2 (1/2^(s)) (a[s, 2, i] - a[s, 1, i]) <= x < (a[s, 1, i] + a[s, 2, i])/2
              + 1/2 (1/2^(s)) (a[s, 2, i] - a[s, 1, i]), {x}]
(*Changes 3^(i-1)th interval of A_n into three intervals using the description above the attempt.*)

Combining the $3^{n-1}$ changed intervals into a total of $3^n$ new intervals
A[s_] := Reduce[Flatten[Table[A[s, i], {i, 1, 3^(s - 1)}]], {s}]
(*Combines all 3^(i-1)th intervals for all i-values*)
B[s_] := Reduce[Flatten[Table[B[s, i], {i, 1, 3^(s - 1)}]], {s}]
(*Combines all 3^(i-1)th intervals for all i-values*)
A[3] (*A3*)
B[3](*B3*)

The problem is the code works for A[2] and B[2]
0 <= x <= 7/24 || 3/8 <= x < 2/3 || 19/24 <= x < 7/8

7/24 <= x < 3/8 || 2/3 <= x <= 19/24 || 7/8 <= x < 1

However, the rest of the code returns $Recursionlimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded.... Even if we fix the code, there's a more efficient way of writing the programming.
Question: How should we write the code? Is there a more efficient method?

Does it matter that the intervals are half-open? Will the math work out the same if we use closed intervals, ie. $A_1 = [0, 2/3]$? In that case, you can try leveraging the Interval construct in Mathematica.

@Domen Well, I defined $A_n$ and $B_n$ as half-open intervals since I wanted to partition the reals into sets $A$ and $B$ which are dense (with positive  measure) in every sub-interval of $(a,b)$ of $\mathbb{R}$. For more info see this and this post. Hence, it wouldn't be mathematically appropriate if we have that all intervals in $A_n$ and $B_n$ are closed.

@Domen Either way, I'm sure the code wouldn't work. There is some minor errors that I'm unable to fix. Also, the code is inefficent. I was hoping someone could find better coding.

Really, all you need are the endpoints, right? So why not just work directly with the lists of endpoints rather than with intervals, and then solving a set of equations?  It seems like you should be able to construct the endpoints directly, but perhaps I'm not understanding the construction.

@march What about graphing $A_n$ and $B_n$? For that case, you should know the intervals.

Sure, but once you have the endpoints, you can directly convert those into intervals.  I can post an answer that leaves it in the final form as in your OP, but I don't get the same answer as you, so I might be misunderstanding the construction. Let me play with my code a little and see what I can do with it. Stay tuned.

@march Thank you.

For $A_1 = [2/3,1)$, we want to take out the middle $1/2^{1+1}=1/4$. Then, it seems like it should be split into three pieces of length 5/24, 1/4, and 5/24, because 5/24+1/4+5/24=2/3. So the intervals should be $[0,5/24]$, $[5/24,11/24)$, and $[11/24,2/3)$, but that's not what you have. You have $A_1$ broken up into intervals of length 7/24, 1/12, and 7/24. Can you clarify? Do you mean to take out the middle 1/4 of the length of the interval rather than just an interval of length 1/4? Actually, that's got to be it. But let me know.

I think I'm misunderstanding something about the cuts. So for $B_1=(2/3,1]$ we cut out the middle $\frac{1}{2^1}$, so since 5/6 is the center of the interval  we take away $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$ from each side of the center? So the cut interval is $[\frac{5}{6} - \frac{1}{4} , \frac{5}{6} + \frac{1}{4}] = \left[\frac{7}{12},\frac{13}{12}\right]$ ? But the endpoint is bigger than 1 and it's not the same as your cuts. Am I not doing something correct?

@march You guys are right, it should be $1/2^{1+1}=1/4$, not $1/2^{2+1}=1/8$...Though, it's too late to make changes to my code.

Here is code that generates the endpoints of the intervals
Clear[a, b]
a[1] = {{0, 2/3}}; b[1] = {{2/3, 1}};
a[n_] := a[n] = Join[Flatten[{{#1, #1 + (#2 - #1)/2 - (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 2)}, {#1 + (#2 - #1)/2 + (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 2), #2}} & @@@a[n - 1], 1], {#1 + (#2 - #1)/2 - (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 1), #1 + (#2 - #1)/2 + (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 1)} & @@@ b[n - 1]] // Sort
b[n_] := b[n] = Join[Flatten[{{#1, #1 + (#2 - #1)/2 - (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 1)}, {#1 + (#2 - #1)/2 + (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 1), #2}} & @@@b[n - 1], 1], {#1 + (#2 - #1)/2 - (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 2), #1 + (#2 - #1)/2 + (#2 - #1)/2^(n + 2)} & @@@ a[n - 1]] // Sort

a[2]
b[2]
(* {{0, 7/24}, {3/8, 2/3}, {19/24, 7/8}} *)
(* {{7/24, 3/8}, {2/3, 19/24}, {7/8, 1}} *)

These functions are memoized so that we eliminate any recursion depth problem. (That means that every time you changed the definitions, you'll need to Clear[a, b], as I've shown.)
To convert this to the interval form desired by the OP, we do
Prepend[#1 <= x < #2 & @@@ Rest@#, #1 <= x <= #2 & @@ First@#] &@a[2]
Prepend[#1 <= x < #2 & @@@ Rest@#, #1 <= x <= #2 & @@ First@#] &@b[2]
(* {0 <= x <= 7/24, 3/8 <= x < 2/3, 19/24 <= x < 7/8} *)
(* {7/24 <= x <= 3/8, 2/3 <= x < 19/24, 7/8 <= x < 1} *)


@Arbuja I had an error in the post; I've fixed it now (I think: you should verify). I have chosen the powers of 2 so that they match your results at the end of your OP. To change this to match the algorithm described in the opening paragraph of your post, change the powers of 2: $1/2^{n+1}$ should be replaced by $1/2^n$ and $1/2^{n+2}$ should be replaced by $1/2^{n+1}$.

@Arbuja. While we don't run into recursion depth issues, it will take a long time to compute this for large $n$.  For instance, a[10] takes 0.7 seconds, a[11] takes 2.5 seconds, and a[12] takes 7.3 seconds (starting from scratch anyway). I think the computation time rises exponentially: roughly, computing the $n$'th steps costs as much (or twice-ish as much) time as all of the $m<n-1$ steps combined.

Thanks. You were originally correct. $1/2^{n+1}$ should be $1/2^{n}$ and $1/2^{n+2}$ should be $1/2^{n+1}$. You don't have to make any changes.

Sorry for the confusion.
